# Is there a simple Bash tool which can quickly render basic HTML?

Tags: shell, command-line, html

From time to time I need to do a simple task where I output basic HTML into the console.  I'd like to have it minimally rendered, to make it easier to read at a glance. Is there a utility which can handle basic HTML rendering in the shell (think of [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)-style rendering--but not an actual browser)?

For example, sometimes I'll put a `watch` on Apache's `mod_status` page:

```
watch -n 1 curl http://some-server/server-status
```

The output of the page is HTML with some minimal markup, which shows in the shell like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Apache Status</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Apache Server Status for localhost</h1>

<dl><dt>Server Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch</dt>
<dt>Server Built: Jul 22 2014 14:35:25
</dt></dl><hr /><dl>
<dt>Current Time: Wednesday, 19-Nov-2014 15:21:40 UTC</dt>
<dt>Restart Time: Wednesday, 19-Nov-2014 15:13:02 UTC</dt>
<dt>Parent Server Generation: 1</dt>
<dt>Server uptime:  8 minutes 38 seconds</dt>
<dt>Total accesses: 549 - Total Traffic: 2.8 MB</dt>
<dt>CPU Usage: u35.77 s12.76 cu0 cs0 - 9.37% CPU load</dt>
<dt>1.06 requests/sec - 5.6 kB/second - 5.3 kB/request</dt>
<dt>1 requests currently being processed, 9 idle workers</dt>
</dl><pre>__W._______.....................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
</pre>
<p>Scoreboard Key:<br />
"<b><code>_</code></b>" Waiting for Connection,
"<b><code>S</code></b>" Starting up,
"<b><code>R</code></b>" Reading Request,<br />
"<b><code>W</code></b>" Sending Reply,
"<b><code>K</code></b>" Keepalive (read),
"<b><code>D</code></b>" DNS Lookup,<br />
"<b><code>C</code></b>" Closing connection,
"<b><code>L</code></b>" Logging,
"<b><code>G</code></b>" Gracefully finishing,<br />
"<b><code>I</code></b>" Idle cleanup of worker,
"<b><code>.</code></b>" Open slot with no current process</p>
<p />
```

When viewed in Lynx the same HTML is rendered as:
                                                                                                   Apache Status (p1 of 2)
                                        Apache Server Status for localhost

```
   Server Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch
   Server Built: Jul 22 2014 14:35:25
     ________________________________________________________________________________________________________

   Current Time: Wednesday, 19-Nov-2014 15:23:50 UTC
   Restart Time: Wednesday, 19-Nov-2014 15:13:02 UTC
   Parent Server Generation: 1
   Server uptime: 10 minutes 48 seconds
   Total accesses: 606 - Total Traffic: 3.1 MB
   CPU Usage: u37.48 s13.6 cu0 cs0 - 7.88% CPU load
   .935 requests/sec - 5088 B/second - 5.3 kB/request
   2 requests currently being processed, 9 idle workers

_C_______W_.....................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
   "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

Comment: Not `bash` exactly, but check out [Xiki](http://xiki.org/), it does that and more

Comment: xiki looks awesome.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`lynx` has a "dump" mode, which you can use with `watch`:

```
$ watch lynx https://www.google.com -dump
```

[image: screenshot of output]

From [`man lynx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lynx.1.html):

```
   -dump  dumps  the  formatted  output  of  the default document or those
          specified on  the  command  line  to  standard  output.   Unlike
          interactive mode, all documents are processed.  This can be used
          in the following way:

          lynx -dump http://www.subir.com/lynx.html

          Files specified on the command line are  formatted  as  HTML  if
          their  names  end  with one of the standard web suffixes such as
          “.htm” or “.html”.  Use the -force_html option to  format  files
          whose names do not follow this convention.
```

This [Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58416/how-can-i-preview-html-documents-from-the-command-line) has many more options.

Comment: lynx is great. it's also a really useful tool when your connection is very bad and you need to go check a site for something - no images, scripts or css makes for a fast page load

Comment: in case someone wants to pipe the curl output. `curl www.google.de | lynx -stdin` sauce: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271946/140177

Answer (score 18):

`w3m` is another program that has a `-dump` option.

It is the backend Emacs' most popular web browser.

Answer (score 11):

There are at least two programs named `html2text` ([1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text)) ([2](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/)) which do this job.

Comment: Indeed but -- if available -- the output of `w3m` is much more beautiful esp. for tables.

Answer (score 9):

`elinks` has `-dump` mode too

```
elinks -dump https://www.google.com
```

Comment: See also [`links`](http://links.twibright.com/) on which `elinks` is based. Same command works...

Answer (score 5):

For a different kind of approach, [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) can convert between many formats, including from html to plain text, and you can give it a URL directly to convert html to something else,

`pandoc --to plain https://example.net`

Or if you want a little formatting, you can use markdown output:

`pandoc --to markdown https://example.net`